# How to get a DataGridView Row as Bitmap for a cursor icon?

Tags: c#, datagridview, bitmap

I'm trying to get a DataGridViews row as Bitmap to use it as a cursors icon.
Sadly the DataGridViewRow object has no DrawToBitmap method.

I managed to get the bound of the row (RowRect) and get a Bitmap of the whole DataGridView (bmp). I think I next need to cut the row from the bitmap, but I have no idea how to do that.

Here is my starting code:

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            rw = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
            Rectangle RowRect = dataGridView1.GetRowDisplayRectangle(rw.Index, true);
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(RowRect.Width, RowRect.Height);
            dataGridView1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size));
            Cursor cur = new Cursor(bmp.GetHicon());
            Cursor.Current = cur;
            rowIndexFromMouseDown = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
            dataGridView1.DoDragDrop(rw, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to grab the **whole** clientarea content first (your bitmap is too small!), then cut out the row rectangle. Also make sure to **dispose** of the created resources!

This should work:

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

    if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Size dgvSz = dataGridView1.ClientSize;
            int rw = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
            Rectangle RowRect = dataGridView1.GetRowDisplayRectangle(rw, true);
            using (Bitmap bmpDgv = new Bitmap(dgvSz.Width, dgvSz.Height))
            using (Bitmap bmpRow = new Bitmap(RowRect.Width, RowRect.Height))
            {
                dataGridView1.DrawToBitmap(bmpDgv , new Rectangle(Point.Empty, dgvSz));
                using ( Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmpRow ))
                    G.DrawImage(bmpDgv , new Rectangle(Point.Empty, 
                                RowRect.Size), RowRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                Cursor.Current.Dispose();   // not quite sure if this is needed
                Cursor cur = new Cursor(bmpRow .GetHicon());
                Cursor.Current = cur;
                rowIndexFromMouseDown = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
                dataGridView1.DoDragDrop(rw, DragDropEffects.Move);
            }
        }
    }
}
```